# Wrong Unix time stamp while updating events drag & drop in full calendar

Tags: php, jquery, fullcalendar, joomla2.5, unix-timestamp

The events fetched from the database displaying correctly in the full calendar.

When I try to drag and drop the events to another date, it gives wrong Unix timestamp.

For example)

The events is currently in November 16 2012, when I drag and drop it to 20 November 2012, it gives the Unix time stamp as 1353340800000 and the date after converting using `strtotime()` PHP function, the result is 1983-07-03.

Issue Fixed :

Check the updated code below.

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({

            editable: true,

            eventDrop: function(calEvent,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revetFunc) {
                var stDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, 'dd-MM-yyyyy');
                $.post('event_update.php',{'allday':allDay, 'event':calEvent.id, 'start':stDate}, function(response){
                    if(response.length > 0){
                       alert(response);
                       revertFunc();
                    }
            });
            },

            loading: function(bool) {
                if (bool) $('#loading').show();
                else $('#loading').hide();
            }

        });
```

Comment: Too many (3) trailing zeroes...

Answer (score 0):

You have to cut the last 3 zeros.

Comment: After removing last three zeros, still I have the issue.  For Example)  got the time stamp as 1355328000000, using substr removed the last 3 zeros. And my result is 1970-01-01. :(

Comment: Got the solution and fixed it. $('#calendar').fullCalendar({

   editable: true,

   eventDrop: function(calEvent,dayDelta,minuteDelta,allDay,revetFunc) {
    var stDate = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(calEvent.start, 'dd-MM-yyyyy');
          $.post('event_update.php',{'allday':allDay, 'event':calEvent.id, 'start':stDate}, function(response){
              if(response.length > 0){
                 alert(response);
                 revertFunc();
              }
          });
   },

   loading: function(bool) {
    if (bool) $('#loading').show();
    else $('#loading').hide();
   }

  });

Comment: Removing last 3 Zeros is a correct timestamp: http://www.unixtimestamp.org/1355328000